# Forward slash in python3 regex seems to negate non-greedy operator

Tags: python, regex

I have observed the following odd behavior of "/" in Python 3. First, if I want to match an arbitrary string within "<" and ">" non-greedily, and replace it with the string "eat", the following works fine:

```
regex = re.compile("<.*?>")
thing = "This <butts> is <pause/> a thing"
newthing = regex.sub("eat",thing)
print(newthing)
```

... outputs the string "This eat is eat a thing" as expected.

However, if I want to match only "", including the forward slash in the regex seems to make the ".*" greedy again:

```
regex = re.compile("<.*?/>")
thing = "This <butts> is <pause/> a thing"
newthing = regex.sub("eat",thing)
print(newthing)
```

...outputs "This eat a thing", and not the expected "This  is eat a thing".

Replacing "/" in the regex with "(/)" or "/" or "[/]" or "[/]" does not help.

And yet, I cannot find any reference to forward slash being a special character in Python regexes. Can someone explain this behavior?

Thank you!

Comment: Use `<[^>]*/>`.

Comment: You can also use  `r"<.*?/>"` i.e `re.compile(r"<.*?/>")`

Comment: "<[^>]*/>" is actually the solution I ended up using, but I still don't understand why it was necessary. re.compile(r"<.*?/>") does not lead to different behavior.

Comment: You can see the `.` and `[^>]` difference: `.` matches anything, `[^>]` does not match `>`. The  regex pattern `.*?` goes on and up to the place where next pattern matches, if there is `/>` somewhere, `.*?` would find it.